# A differential equation with a hidden sentence

Tags: mathematics, steganography

> Find the specialized solution of $H''(r)-aH'(r)=0$ that satisfies $H'(0) = \frac{1}{p^2}$ and $H(0) = \frac{H'(0)}{a}(1+\frac{N}{Y}e^w)$

The question:

1. Solve the above mathematic question
2. Rewrite your solution to 1 in an appropriate form
3. (Optional) *This might be a hint (to some extents)*

   > Speak your answer to task 2 out loud!

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not the original author of this puzzle. It was an image that showed up in an instant messaging group. The original image contains solution for 1 and 2 and is written in my native language - Simplified Chinese.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like:

> Happy New Year

Update:

Here's my solution:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Part 1:

> Start from $H''(r)-aH'(r)=0$ and let $G(r) = H'(r)$, so $G'(r)-aG(r)=0$. The general solution for this linear equation is $G(r) = be^{ar}$ ($b$ constant). Now $\frac{1}{p^2} = H'(0) = G(0) = b$. Integrating $G(r)$ gives $H(r) = \frac{e^{ar}}{a p^2}+C$ ($C$ constant). $H(0) = \frac{1}{a p^2} + C$, so
>
>  $$\frac{1}{a p^2} + C = \frac{H'(0)}{a}(1+\frac{N}{Y}e^w) = \frac{1}{a p^2}+\frac{Ne^w}{a p^2 Y}$$
>
>  so $C = \frac{Ne^w}{a p^2 Y}$ and
>
>  $$H = \frac{e^{ar}}{a p^2}+\frac{Ne^w}{a p^2 Y}$$

Part 2:

> Rewriting this becomes
>
>  $$H=\frac{Ne^w}{a p p Y} + \frac{Y e^{ar}}{a p p Y}$$
>
>  and finally
>
>  $$H a p p Y = N e^w + Y e^{a r}$$

or, as @pirate correctly guessed,

> Happy New Year

Comment: G(rrr) = bear is also a nice stylistic choice of variables.